# Download Returned Zip file from URL

Tags: python, url, download, zip, urllib

If I have a URL that, when submitted in a web browser, pops up a dialog box to save a zip file, how would I go about catching and downloading this zip file in Python?

Comment: I tried section **Downloading a binary file and writing it to disk** of [this page](http://www.compciv.org/practicum/shakefiles/b-downloading-the-shakespeare-zip/) which worked as a chram.

Comment: For anyone else looking for a solution with only the standard library stuff, then check out this answer - https://stackoverflow.com/a/31706921/8604951 and save yourself a couple of minutes of reading and scrolling through the rest of the answers which uses `requests` (which btw is an amazing library and I would use it if it was possible to do son.

Answer (score 81, accepted):

Most people recommend using `requests` if it is available, and the `requests` [documentation](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/quickstart/#raw-response-content) recommends this for downloading and saving raw data from a url:

```
import requests 

def download_url(url, save_path, chunk_size=128):
    r = requests.get(url, stream=True)
    with open(save_path, 'wb') as fd:
        for chunk in r.iter_content(chunk_size=chunk_size):
            fd.write(chunk)
```

Since the answer asks about downloading *and saving* the zip file, I haven't gone into details regarding reading the zip file. See one of the many answers below for possibilities.

If for some reason you don't have access to `requests`, you can use `urllib.request` instead. It may not be quite as robust as the above.

```
import urllib.request

def download_url(url, save_path):
    with urllib.request.urlopen(url) as dl_file:
        with open(save_path, 'wb') as out_file:
            out_file.write(dl_file.read())
```

Finally, if you are using Python 2 still, you can use `urllib2.urlopen`.

```
from contextlib import closing

def download_url(url, save_path):
    with closing(urllib2.urlopen(url)) as dl_file:
        with open(save_path, 'wb') as out_file:
            out_file.write(dl_file.read())
```

Answer (score 312):

As far as I can tell, the proper way to do this in Python 2 is:

```
import requests, zipfile, StringIO
r = requests.get(zip_file_url, stream=True)
z = zipfile.ZipFile(StringIO.StringIO(r.content))
z.extractall()
```

of course you'd want to check that the GET was successful with `r.ok`.

For python 3+, sub the StringIO module with the [io](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html) module and use BytesIO instead of StringIO: [Here](https://docs.python.org/3.0/whatsnew/3.0.html#text-vs-data-instead-of-unicode-vs-8-bit) are release notes that mention this change.

```
import requests, zipfile, io
r = requests.get(zip_file_url)
z = zipfile.ZipFile(io.BytesIO(r.content))
z.extractall("/path/to/destination_directory")
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer. I used it to solve [my issue getting a zip file with requests](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36779870/python-requests-not-returning-same-header-as-browser-request-curl/36990934#36990934).

Comment: yoavram, in your code- where i enter the url of the webpage?

Comment: If you'd like to save the downloaded file in a different location, replace `z.extractall()` with `z.extractall("/path/to/destination_directory")`

Comment: @newGIS I hope you figured it out by now, but the url of the zip you want to download is `zip_file_url`.

Comment: @yoavram I was desperately looking for this answer. Can you tell me how to save the content as ".zip" file. If I do `extractall()` it extracts the content. I don't want that.

Comment: If you just want to save the file from the url you can do: `urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, filename)`.

Comment: To help others connect the dots it took me 60minutes too long to, you can then use `pd.read_table(z.open('filename'))` with the above. Useful if you have a zip url link that contains multiple files and you're only interested in loading one.

Comment: how to print the status of extracting?

Comment: @yoavram How can I test these 3 lines if I put it in a function using Mock?

Comment: not the right pattern according to https://2.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#raw-response-content

Comment: what if the .zip file is over 10GB, won't the get() mess up with the memory?

Comment: When I do `z = zipfile.ZipFile(io.BytesIO(r.content))`, I get `zipfile.BadZipFile: File is not a zip file`.

Comment: I also get zipfile.BadZipFile: File is not a zip file with status code 400

Answer (score 20):

With the help of [this blog post](https://web.archive.org/web/20210225194328/http://masnun.com/2016/09/18/python-using-the-requests-module-to-download-large-files-efficiently.html), I've got it working with just `requests`.
The point of the weird `stream` thing is so we don't need to call `content`
on large requests, which would require it to all be processed at once,
clogging the memory. The `stream` avoids this by iterating through the data
one chunk at a time.

```py
url = 'https://www2.census.gov/geo/tiger/GENZ2017/shp/cb_2017_02_tract_500k.zip'

response = requests.get(url, stream=True)
with open('alaska.zip', "wb") as f:
    for chunk in response.iter_content(chunk_size=512):
        if chunk:  # filter out keep-alive new chunks
            f.write(chunk)
```

Comment: Answers should not rely on links for the bulk of their content. Links can go dead, or the content on the other side can be changed to no longer answer the question. Please edit your answer to include a summary or explanation of the information you link points to.

Comment: What is `chunk_size` here? And can this parameter affect the speed of downloading?

Comment: @ayushthakur Here are some links that may help: [`requests.Response.iter_content`](https://2.python-requests.org/en/master/api/#requests.Response.iter_content) and [wikipedia:Chunk Transfer Encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chunked_transfer_encoding). Someone else could probably give a better answer, but I wouldn't expect `chunk_size` to make of a difference for download speed if it's set large enough (reducing #pings/content ratio). 512 bytes seems super small in retrospect.

Answer (score 15):

Here's what I got to work in Python 3:

```
import zipfile, urllib.request, shutil

url = 'http://www....myzipfile.zip'
file_name = 'myzip.zip'

with urllib.request.urlopen(url) as response, open(file_name, 'wb') as out_file:
    shutil.copyfileobj(response, out_file)
    with zipfile.ZipFile(file_name) as zf:
        zf.extractall()
```

Comment: Hello. How can avoid this error: `urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 302: The HTTP server returned a redirect error that would lead to an infinite loop.`?

Comment: @VictorHerasmePerez, an HTTP 302 response status code means that the page has been moved. I think the issue your facing is addressed here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32569934/urlopen-returning-redirect-error-for-valid-links

Comment: @Webucator What if the zipped folder contains several files, then all those files will get extracted and stored in the system.I want to extract and get just one file from the zipped folder. Any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 9):

Super lightweight solution to save a .zip file to a location on disk (using Python 3.9):

```
import requests

url = r'https://linktofile'
output = r'C:\pathtofolder\downloaded_file.zip'

r = requests.get(url)
with open(output, 'wb') as f:
    f.write(r.content)
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68524210/how-to-bypass-the-alert-window-while-downloading-a-zipfile

Comment: @AtomStore yes? Is there an issue with my answer?

Comment: how to bypass the alert, it downloads the html file rather than zip

Comment: My answer works for the link I tested with. Try using my code, but replacing the url with: https://api.os.uk/downloads/v1/products/CodePointOpen/downloads?area=GB&format=GeoPackage&redirect (open data from Ordnance Survey)

Answer (score 7):

I came here searching how to save a .bzip2 file. Let me paste the code for others who might come looking for this.

```
url = "http://api.mywebsite.com"
filename = "swateek.tar.gz"

response = requests.get(url, headers=headers, auth=('myusername', 'mypassword'), timeout=50)
if response.status_code == 200:
with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
   f.write(response.content)
```

I just wanted to save the file as is.

Answer (score 6):

Either use urllib2.urlopen, or you could try using the excellent [`Requests`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/index.html) module and avoid urllib2 headaches:

```
import requests
results = requests.get('url')
#pass results.content onto secondary processing...
```

Comment: But how do you parse results.content int a zip?

Comment: Use the `zipfile` module:

`zip = zipfile.ZipFile(results.content)`.

Then just parse through the files using `ZipFile.namelist()`, `ZipFile.open()`, or `ZipFile.extractall()`

Answer (score 4):

Thanks to @yoavram for the above solution,
 my url path linked to a zipped **folder**, and encounter an error of BADZipfile 
 (file is not a zip file), and it was strange if I tried several times it 
 retrieve the url and unzipped it all of sudden so I amend the solution a little 
 bit. using the *is_zipfile* method as per [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html#zipfile.is_zipfile)

```
r = requests.get(url, stream =True)
check = zipfile.is_zipfile(io.BytesIO(r.content))
while not check:
    r = requests.get(url, stream =True)
    check = zipfile.is_zipfile(io.BytesIO(r.content))
else:
    z = zipfile.ZipFile(io.BytesIO(r.content))
    z.extractall()
```

Answer (score 3):

### Use `requests, zipfile and io` python packages.

Specially BytesIO function is used to keep the unzipped file in memory rather than saving it into the drive.

```
import requests
from zipfile import ZipFile
from io import BytesIO

r = requests.get(zip_file_url)
z = ZipFile(BytesIO(r.content))    
file = z.extract(a_file_to_extract, path_to_save)
with open(file) as f:
    print(f.read())
```

Comment: Thank you! Can't believe I had to scroll all the way to the last answer to find one that used requests and didn't write to a file.