# How to download a zip file from the raw binary returned by a requests POST endpoint?

Tags: python, python-3.x, post, zip, python-requests

I need to hit a POST endpoint and save the response which is a binary data as a zip file and download it to my local directory. I have managed to hit the POST endpoint and retrieve the binary data but I am struggling to convert that or save that as a zip file.

The function download_contract is the POST I use to hit the endpoint where contract is the JSON I'm parsing:

```
def post(cls, url, access_token, obj=None):
    return WebResponse.from_requests(requests.post(url, data=None if obj is None else obj.json(), headers=cls.secure_header(access_token) if obj is None else cls.secure_json_header(access_token)))

def download_contract(self, contract):
    return SecureWebRequest.post(self.CONTRACT_EXPORT_URL, obj=contract, access_token=self.access_token)
```

The following code is about me hitting the endpoint and retrieving it's response and trying to save it as a zip file.

```
@then(u'I will download file from S3')
def step_impl(context):
    print(context.response)
    file_name = 'myzip.zip'
    with context.services.autoimport.download_contract(DownloadContract(context.program_id, complete_filename(context.filename))) as response, open(file_name, 'wb') as out_file:
        shutil.copyfileobj(response, out_file)
        with zipfile.ZipFile(file_name) as zf:
            zf.extractall()
```

What's returned when I print(context.response) is as follows:

> WebResponse(200,m_-Jinstrument.xmlmPÍ Â0
>   žď)B_`ÖQ1CđŕYń8ĘI`kGßŢˇ)Ă\ň}|?FłČeqÁťť×=Lť&sRÁĐxÜăcŇĽHżÁ:Źů9
>   üż7OĚhtÓé`Ä#CŤ3>ÚŇŞV­hŕşwZÂč8yłś 32Wű\ep

WebResponse is the (status_code, result) where status_code corresponds to the HTTP Status code of 200 and result is the raw data returned by the endpoint.

```
class WebResponse():
    STATUS_OK = 200
    STATUS_CREATED = 201
    STATUS_ACCEPTED = 202
    STATUS_NOCONTENT = 204
    STATUS_BADREQUEST = 400
    STATUS_UNAUTHORIZED = 401
    STATUS_FORBIDDEN = 403
    STATUS_NOTFOUND = 404
    STATUS_CONFLICT = 409
    STATUS_INVALID = 422
    STATUS_INTERNALSERVER_ERROR = 500

    def __init__(self, r, result=None):
        self.status_code = r.status_code
        self.text = r.text
        self.headers = r.headers
        self.result = r.text if result is None else result

    def __repr__(self):
        return 'WebResponse(%s, %s)' % (self.status_code, self.result)
```

Error Thrownback:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "/Users/ss/anaconda/envs/autoimport-server/lib/python3.4/site-packages/behave/model.py",
>   line 1456, in run
>       match.run(runner.context)   File "/Users/ss/anaconda/envs/autoimport-server/lib/python3.4/site-packages/behave/model.py",
>   line 1903, in run
>       self.func(context, *args, **kwargs)   File "features/steps/miu_connector_steps.py", line 255, in step_impl
>       with context.services.autoimport.download_contract(DownloadContract(context.program_id,
>   complete_filename(context.filename))) as response, open(file_name,
>   'wb') as out_file: AttributeError: **exit**

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9419208/6626530 -  may be you should to try  urllib2.urlopen

Comment: @Shijo That requires a link with the zip file in it though, I only have a POST endpoint which I can only hit. i.e. "http://accautoimport.miuinsights.com/v1/contractsExport"

Comment: how about http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13137817/how-to-download-image-using-requests

Answer (score 0):

Your response looks like `'WebResponse(200,m_-Jins ...'` and that is what you are writing into a file `shutil.copyfileobj(response, out_file)`.

I assume you want to write `response.result` into the file.
Btw. what is the content in out_file ?

Comment: Yes, I want to write `response.result` into the file.
Nothing, it fails before it gets to that line

Comment: Whats the error (edit your post with full traceback) ?

Comment: I get the following back when I try your suggested solution out.
`shutil.copyfileobj(context.response.result, f)
  File "/Users/ss/anaconda/envs/autoimport-server/lib/python3.4/shutil.py", line 67, in copyfileobj
    buf = fsrc.read(length)
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'read'`

Comment: I've added the full traceback to the post above.

Answer (score 0):

The **init** below was missing a `r.raw` where `r` refers to the `requests`.

```
class WebResponse():
    STATUS_OK = 200
    STATUS_CREATED = 201
    STATUS_ACCEPTED = 202
    STATUS_NOCONTENT = 204
    STATUS_BADREQUEST = 400
    STATUS_UNAUTHORIZED = 401
    STATUS_FORBIDDEN = 403
    STATUS_NOTFOUND = 404
    STATUS_CONFLICT = 409
    STATUS_INVALID = 422
    STATUS_INTERNALSERVER_ERROR = 500

    def __init__(self, r, result=None):
        self.status_code = r.status_code
        self.text = r.text
        self.headers = r.headers
        self.raw = r.raw
        self.result = r.text if result is None else result
```

I then changed my code to the following to get it working:

```
@then(u'I will download the zip file from the service')
def step_impl(context):
    with open(context.filename, 'wb') as fd:
        for chunk in context.response.iter_content(chunk_size=128):
            fd.write(chunk)
```