# Python getting error "UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xad in position 10: invalid start byte"

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, python-requests

I am trying to download a csv file with the following code:

```
import requests

url = 'https://www.bjs.gov/content/pub/sheets/mhtip.zip'

res = requests.get(url, allow_redirects=True)

csv = res.content.decode('utf-8')
print(csv)
```

but I get this error:

> UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xad in position 10: invalid start byte

After searching google with this error, I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22216076/unicodedecodeerror-utf8-codec-cant-decode-byte-0xa5-in-position-0-invalid-s) answer:

```
import requests

url = 'https://www.bjs.gov/content/pub/sheets/mhtip.zip'

res = requests.get(url, allow_redirects=True)

csv = res.content.encode('utf-8').strip()
print(csv)
```

But get:

> AttributeError: 'bytes' object has no attribute 'encode'

What am I missing here?

Comment: The url provides a zip file havind **several** csv files. What to you want to do ? Read one of them ?

Comment: @AlexandreB. I am trying to "download them", but thought I could print their contents to terminal

Comment: I think that answers my question though, I need to "unzip" them first.  thanks

Comment: Glad to help you, cheers :)

Comment: please check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14260592/8353711). It is already answered.