# Python requests.get returns Gibberish

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests

I'm trying to scrape the following URL:

```
link='https://www.opensubtitles.org/en/subtitleserve/sub/6646133'
```

When I do

`html = requests.get(link)`

it returns in

`html.content`

Gibberish (starting at `b'PK\x03\x04\x14\x00\x00\x00\x08\x00z\x8c8Q\xd5H\xc5\xd7\xaf7\x00\x00\xdf\x95\x00\x00^\x00\x00\x00`...)

Why I'm not getting clear text?

Comment: `PK` is a zip file or something like a zip. You've grabbed an archive, and that's its binary data.

Comment: Using `curl`, I get no response from that link, and it redirects in the browser

Comment: Good start, so how I should unzip/transform it?

Comment: please provide [mcve]. and it's better to use `html.text`

Comment: @buran you have the link and the get command, what is more reproducible than that?

Comment: I get nice html and it looks ike you are accessing something different

Comment: I also can't reproduce this. There are unzipping libraries though that likely take streams of binary data.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `zipfile` to [unzip it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14260592/2614364) and then check the filenames. If you are interested in extracting the srt files, the following will get the content :

```python
import requests, zipfile, io

r = requests.get("https://www.opensubtitles.org/en/subtitleserve/sub/6646133",
    headers = {
        "referer": "https://www.opensubtitles.org/en/subtitles/6646133/america-s-got-talent-audition-1-en"
})
z = zipfile.ZipFile(io.BytesIO(r.content))
filenames = z.namelist()
print(filenames)
srt_files = [t for t in filenames if t.endswith(".srt")]
for t in srt_files:
    content = z.read(t)
    print(content)
```

[run it on repl.it](https://repl.it/@bertrandmartel/unzipSubtitles)