# downloading a zipped file using python 3.7

Tags: python, get, request, zip

So guys, I have this file thay I need to download using python, and this is my code

```
import requests

url = "http://servicos.ibama.gov.br/ctf/publico/areasembargadas/downloadListaAreasEmbargadas.php"

response = requests.get(url)

url = open("test.zip", "wb+")
url.write(response.content)
url.close()
```

if you click into the link you'll see that it is a zipped file, that's why i put the .zip extension, it downloads the file but it is a file that can't be opened, I have a feeling that I am doing something wrong.

Also I tryied to change it to .txt so I could see the content of what it was downloading and I saw that it saves only the HTML code of the page that redirects me to the downloading URL, quite frankly I am as lost as one can be

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Download Returned Zip file from URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9419162/download-returned-zip-file-from-url)

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in the ansyer of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9419162/download-returned-zip-file-from-url) post:

```
import requests 

def download_url(url, save_path, chunk_size=128):
    r = requests.get(url, stream=True)
    with open(save_path, 'wb') as fd:
        for chunk in r.iter_content(chunk_size=chunk_size):
            fd.write(chunk)
```

with save_path the location of where you want to save your file.

Comment: i did exactly this and the program runs, but when I go to the location i gave as path there is nothing there

Comment: Did you give an absolute path or a relative one? You can try to just use a filename (like "test.zip") and see if you can find the file "test.zip" at the same place you executed your code. If it is the case, then you are probably not looking at the rigth place when using your full save_path

Answer (score 0):

Here is a one liner. Notice the `b` next to `w` for bytes.

```
from urllib.request import urlopen


open('Sample1.zip', 'wb').write(urlopen('http://servicos.ibama.gov.br/ctf/publico/areasembargadas/downloadListaAreasEmbargadas.php').read())
```