How to Handle Window based popup in Automation using Selenium?
When I am trying to download a file from Browser. Download File location popup is displayed. Is there a way to handle this window popup using Selenium 4 ? There are 2 buttons in this popup 1. Cancel and Another is Save. How to Press Cancel using Selenium 4 ?
I have tried using Action Class like
new Actions(driver).keyDown(Keys.CANCEL).keyUp(Keys.CANCEL);

but still not able to close this window-based popup.

check if this helps you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35331854/downloading-a-file-at-a-specified-location-through-python-and-selenium-using-chr

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68524210/how-to-bypass-the-alert-window-while-downloading-a-zipfile
