# Get zip file from url with python3 request : make it more verbose

Tags: python, python-3.x, request, wget

I try this to load a zip file from a url.

```
import requests

resp = requests.get('https://nlp.stanford.edu/data/glove.6B.zip')
```

I now the file is colossal, and I don't know in between if everything is going well or not.

(1) Is there a way to make the loading more verbose ?

(2) How do I know where data are loaded, and is there a relative path for it, which I can use for implementing the rest of my script ?

(3) How to nicely unzip ?

(4) How to either choose/set a file name or get the file name for the downloaded file ?

Comment: [This article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9419162/download-returned-zip-file-from-url) can give you a good example.

Answer (score 1):

*Is there a way to make the loading more verbose ?*

If you want to download file to disk and be aware how many bytes were already downloaded you might use [`urrlib.request.urlretrieve`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html#urllib.request.urlretrieve) from built-in module `urllib.request`. It does accept optional `reporthook`. This should be function which accept 3 arguments, it will be called at begin and end of each chunk with:

- number of chunk
- size of chunk
- total size or 1 if unknown

Simple example which prints to stdout progress as fraction

```
from urllib.request import urlretrieve
def report(num, size, total):
    print(num*size, '/', total)
urlretrieve("http://www.example.com","index.html",reporthook=report)
```

This does download [www.example.com](http://www.example.com/) to current working directory as `index.html` reporting progress by `print`ing. Note that fraction might be > 1 and should be treated as estimate.

EDIT: After download of zip file end, if you want to just unpack whole archive you might use [`shutil.unpack_archive`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html#shutil.unpack_archive) from `shutil` built-in module. If more fine grained control is desired you might use [`zipfile`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html) built-in module, in [PyMOTW3 entry for zipfile](https://pymotw.com/3/zipfile/index.html) you might find examples like listing files inside ZIP archive, reading selected file from ZIP archive, reading metadata of file inside ZIP archive.

Comment: Not really esthetical :)

Comment: what is the current working directory ? ---> os.getcwd()

Comment: @kiriloff yes `os.getcwd()` returns current working directory

Comment: it was an affirmation