# Python: AttributeError: Response.read and .text not working

Tags: python, python-requests, attributeerror

Here is my code:

```
import requests

feeds = []

for i in range(2002, 2023):
    feeds.append(str(i))

for feed in feeds:
    link = f"https://nvd.nist.gov/feeds/json/cve/1.1/nvdcve-1.1-{feed}.json.zip"
    response = requests.get(link)
    if response.status_code == 200:
        print("Success")
        with open(f"{feed}.zip", "wb") as f:
            f.write(response.read())
```

However, when I use `response.read()` on the last line, it gives me this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\30kal\database.py", line 48, in <module>
    f.write(response.read())
AttributeError: 'Response' object has no attribute 'read'
```

But, when I try to use `response.text`, it gives me this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\30kal\database.py", line 48, in <module>
    f.write(response.text)
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

Any idea why?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Download large file in python with requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16694907/download-large-file-in-python-with-requests)

Comment: It's helpful, but, I don't need help with downloading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting two errors with different causes.

The first occurs because the type `requests.models.Response` that `requests.get` returns does not have a function `read`.

The second occurs because you can't write a `str` type to a file when you open it with the option `"wb"`; that indicates you want to open the file with "write binary" mode, which only accepts bytes-like objects, not strings.

I looked at [Download Returned Zip file from URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9419162/download-returned-zip-file-from-url) to make this modification to your code:

```py
import requests

feeds = map(str,range(2002, 2023))


for feed in feeds:
    link = f"https://nvd.nist.gov/feeds/json/cve/1.1/nvdcve-1.1-{feed}.json.zip"
    response = requests.get(link, stream=True)
    if response.status_code == 200:
        print("Success")
        with open(f"{feed}.zip", "wb") as f:
            for chunk in response.iter_content(chunk_size=512):
                if chunk:  # filter out keep-alive new chunks
                    f.write(chunk)
```

You could take a look at the link for alternatives.